# Add additional LDAP attributes in Wso2 User

Tags: ldap, wso2

I am using Wso2 and i want to manage some additional LDAP information through the Wso2.

Wso2 gives me a basic set of user attributes but how can i extend that set with more attributes which i can then map to LDAP user attributes?